# Local jfrog artifactory does not resolve some dependencies

Tags: maven, artifactory

our local jfrog artifactory has strange issue with only some dependencies. For example, we have issues with jSerialComm artifact of version 2.6.x. Version 2.5.3 was downloaded and cached and it works ok but when I try version 2.6.1 or any other 2.6 version it simply cannot find it. Maven says:

Could not find artifact com.fazecast:jSerialComm:jar:2.6.1 in central

I suspected it could be name issue (capital letters) so I deployed it directly and changed all capital letters to small and added something to the name and then it worked. If I kept the same group and artifact name it did not work.

Then for example apache cxf plugin. New versions are simply not downloaded, only those that are already in.

I am using admin user and for admin it says that he can do anything... What should I do to make it work? Do you need any other info to help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more researching I found out that I had mvnrepository.com added wincorrectly. Those artifacts stared working as soon as I replaced URL value from:

```
mvnrepository.com
```

to

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

I hope this will help someone.